# Cannot find module 'angular-in-memory-web-api' Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have almost finished the tutorial on angular.io. I ran into an issue where I cannot compile due to not being able to find angular-in-memory-web-api.

I import it here in **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';
import { HeroSearchComponent }  from './hero-search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  providers: [ HeroService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And in **in-memory-data.service.ts**

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let heroes = [
      {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
      {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
      {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
      {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
      {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
      {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
      {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
      {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
      {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
      {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'}
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }
}
```

[File list here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxPVC.png)

[File list continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A22Fp.png)

Any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: Is it in your package.json?

Comment: @DeborahK does not look like it is. Am i supposed to add it? How would i go about that?

Comment: Then most likely it is not installed. You'd need to either install it directly with the --save or add it to the package.json and re-run `npm install`.

Comment: And it needs to be in systemjs.config.js as well. I have an example that uses it here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing